# Unknown Error in NetGraph with RTX 3090 GPU

Tags: neural-networks, gpu

I am running NetGraph on my RTX 3090 GPU. The Net itself loads properly in my GPU, having an approximate size of 9GB (the 3090 has 24GB of memory). However, once the net actually starts NetGraph returns an unknown error:

[image]

Once $LastInternalFailure is consulted, it returns:

[image]

The error is related to "too large launch parameter".

Questions: What exactly is this error? Can this be avoided? If so, how?

thank you for your help.

Comment: I would log a case with Wolfram support.